# Upload Static Application Files

Tags: oracle-apex

I tried to upload static application files and get the error "no file selected". I use APEX 19.1.0.00.15 and ORDS 19.1.0.r0921545[image]

Comment: Not everything is displayed on the screenshot; does it contain the file itself, or just the directory that contains that file? Should be *the file*.

Comment: the path with file name: C:\Users\christian.klose\Documents\MQS_KUNDEN\Muniqsoft\LISTENER_REP_LOGANALYZER\APEX\Images\report.jpg

Comment: I've just tried it on 18.2 (my own Apex) and 19.1 (on apex.oracle.com) - works OK in both cases, using Firefox browser.

Comment: Thanks for help.

Comment: No problem. Did you make it work?

Comment: no, I will open a ticket on Oracle Support.

Comment: The cause was, that the indexes of the table FLOWS_FILES.WWV_FLOW_FILE_OBJECTS$ had the status unusable. After rebuild everything works fine.

Comment: Aha. Thank you for letting us know.